# I am creating multiple sliders in a page... but not getting the correct stop position if the number of slides are different from each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating multiple sliders in a page... but not getting the correct stop position if the number of slides are different from each other..

If I keep the number of slides same it works well..

But I need different number of slides in sliders...

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.myslider-wrapper').each(function(){

    // thumbSlide
        var countSlider = $('.thumbSlide').length;
        if((".thumbSlide").length){        
            // Declare variables
            var totalImages = $(".thumbSlide > li").length, 
                imageWidth = $(".thumbSlide > li:first").outerWidth(true),
                totalWidth = imageWidth * totalImages,
                visibleImages = Math.round($(".thumbSlide-wrap").width() / imageWidth),
                visibleWidth = visibleImages * imageWidth,
                stopPosition = (visibleWidth - totalWidth/countSlider);  
            $(".thumbSlide").width(totalWidth+10);
            $(".thumbSlide-prev").click(function(){
                var parentMove = $(this).parent().prev('.thumbSlide');
                if(parentMove.position().left < 0 && !$(".thumbSlide").is(":animated")){
                    parentMove.animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
                }               
                return false;
            });        
            $(".thumbSlide-next").click(function(){
                var parentMove = $(this).parent().prev('.thumbSlide');
                if(parentMove.position().left > stopPosition && !$(".thumbSlide").is(":animated")){
                    parentMove.animate({left : "-=" + imageWidth + "px"});                  
                }               
                return false;
            });
        }

     });
});
```

here is jsFiddle URL:

http://jsfiddle.net/mufeedahmad/GLSqS/

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that all sliders are the same class and js will work through them in the dom order. The first slider has 6 positions and the last only one, but you use jquery to search by class .thumbSlide and have no id to get the length of each slider separately. Thats why i can click right on the last slider as if i was clicking on the first one.

Comment: cant define the ID bcz there could be more than 30 sliders...

the idea is if in a row slides are too much slider will be available to view the items

Comment: Take a look at @RoryKoehein 's answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You iterate through all sliders correctly by doing `$('.myslider-wrapper').each()`, but then you do some stuff with `$('.thumbSlide')` that should be `$('.thumbSlide', this)`.

`$('.thumbSlide')` will select all elements on the page with that class, while `$('.thumbSlide', this)` within the each callback will only select the element in that particular wrapper.

Edit: fixed your jsfiddle with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/GLSqS/1/

Comment: can you please suggest this in jsFiddle link, I have given above...thanks